# Smart Contract not producing results, how do I see both results or get the total count of both results

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

When I deploy the contract I get the count result of only one entity not both entities. Can you help me? How do I get the result of both entities.

Here is part of the code.

```
function doVote(bool _choice)
        public
        inState(State.Voting)
        returns (bool voted)
    {
        bool found = false;
        
        if (bytes(voterRegister[msg.sender].voterName).length != 0 
        && !voterRegister[msg.sender].voted){
            voterRegister[msg.sender].voted = true;
            vote memory v;
            v.voterAddress = msg.sender;
            v.choice = _choice;
            if (_choice){
                countResult++; //counting on the go
            }
            else {
                countRe++; 
            }
            votes[totalVote] = v;
            totalVote++;
            found = true;
        }
        emit voteDone(msg.sender);
        return found;
    }
    
    //end votes
    function endVote()
        public
        inState(State.Voting)
        onlyOfficial
    {
        state = State.Ended;
        finalResult = countResult; //move result from private countResult to public finalResult
        totalFalse = countRe; 
        emit voteEnded(finalResult, totalFalse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain in more detail what you mean